# Common graphics asset format for Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

I have graphics asset for iOS in `.svg` but for Android Studio I have to convert it into android vector assets.

Wondering if there is any common graphics asset format understand by Xcode & Android Studio ?

Comment: Is there any problem in converting svg into vector assets? I think Android Studio has built-in feature to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Mac App called 'Iconizer'. I drag my images into it, set what formats I need (iOS, Android, etc.) and it'll format the images to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, got to `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Resource Manager`.
Then, click on the add '+' icon, and select `Import Drawables`.
[image: Resource Manager]